# Server's .htaccess file blocks all traffic outside of intranet, how to enable just google doc embed despite this?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip, ip-address, google-document-viewer

My Server's .htaccess file is written to block every IP address that is not within my University's network. It looks something like this:

```
order deny,allow
allow from 128.192
allow from 172.16
allow from 172.17
... few more of these...
deny from all
```

The website I'm working on is currently using a framework that allows users to view/upload pdf/word/ppt/jpg/etc files on the site itself. The viewing functionality is enabled via [google doc embed](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html). However, as a result, the server blocks users from seeing the files. I believe it is due to this IP restriction (Once I remove the .htaccess restrictions, the files are viewable again).

e.g. https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.mywebsite.com/images/1.jpg&embed=true

I have tried enabling a handful of google IP ranges (in .htaccess) I found listed on the internet but have had no success so far. Currently, removing the .htaccess file is not an option. Does anyone have any advice for my situation?

EDIT: solution in comments of approved answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look in the access logs to see which IPs Google is using to access your content.

It's unlikely that those will stay the same forever, though.

It's probably best to either move all the affected content to a different subdomain that isn't restricted, or to enable access to the required files for all IPs, on a per-directory or per-file basis, using a [`<directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) or [`<files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) entry.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to implement the last option you presented? Assuming all of my files are located in the "images" directory and its subdirectories. Would it look something like this: <Directory "/var/www/html/images"> allow from all </Directory> ?

Comment: @monty yup, that's what I had in mind. Not an Apache guru myself, but that looks like it should work

Comment: Fixed it. There are two solutions I now know of. First one is to use this <Directory> directive inside the apache config file. The other solution (the one I used) is to add another .htaccess file within the directory that you want to make exceptions for. I added an .htaccess file with the line allow from all in my "images directory" The issue is now resolved. Thanks for the help!